# Where can I find parameter explanation for Kubernetes "kind: StorageClass" "provisioner: docker.io/hostpath"?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

First of all my question is at level 1 of 5 (where 1 is the lowest).

I created some working storage class in Kubernetes - it is nice but I do not understand how can I optimize/adjust this more to my usage need:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local
provisioner: docker.io/hostpath
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: True
```

Where can I find explanation of used parameters for "docker.io/hostpath"?

For example what does mean "volumeBindingMode: Immediate" or "reclaimPolicy: Delete"?
How does works "allowVolumeExpansion: True"?

I know what is "StorageClass" but not understand details.

Comment: Where are you encountering this?  In most cases, as a programmer, you should never need to manually create Kubernetes storage classes, and you shouldn't usually use host-path volumes in Kubernetes (they are a recipe to misplace data if a pod is rescheduled on a different node).

Comment: @DavidMaze "as programmer" - why any programmer should be limited to some specific role - no idea? I need understand how it works because I will program/code and deploy cluster or local environment. I do not want to learn the best practice which is limited usage to the most situation (that is o.k. that it exists but have no use in this case). In general you are right but in this case not.